# When to add properties using CGImageDestinationSetProperties and when to add properties with CGImageDestinationAddImage

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics

I've been looking at creating gif file using CGImageDestinationRef and I haven't been able to find any documentation on which properties I should be applying using CGImageDestinationSetProperties and which properties I should be setting when I add an image to the CGImageDestination object using CGImageDestinationAddImage.

But I realised this problem doesn't just apply to exporting image files as GIF files.

I've looked at some properties returned by CGImageSource and though that supplies some clues it is hit & miss. But for example it seems HasGlobalColorMap and LoopCount should be properties set using CGImageDestinationSetProperties whilst UnclampedDelayTime and DelayTime are properties that should be set when adding an image.

I'm after guidance as to which properties I should be adding to the CGImageDestinationRef directly and which ones should be added when I add an image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wish Apple did a better job explaining these little details. I was scratching my head about this as well.

Looking at [Image I/O Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/ikpg_dest/ikpg_dest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH219-SW3) examples, all properties are set on individual images using `CGImageDestinationAddImage` (although the description there does somehow contradict this...).

In [CGImageProperties Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html) there is a list of all(?) possible keys that are used by `CGImageDestinationSetProperties` and `CGImageDestinationAddImage`. It makes a distinction between individual image keys, format specific keys and *"Image Source Container Properties"* (has only one key):

> **Image Source Container Properties**
>
> Properties that apply to the container in general but not necessarily to any individual image in the container.

It implies (and supported by random sampling trial an error) that all other keys should be set using individual images with `CGImageDestinationAddImage`.

Comment: In the end for me I needed to test things out via trial and error. That was the only way I could determine that both {GIF}.LoopCount and {GIF}.HasGlobalColorMap are set using CGImageDestinationSetProperties.